# TortoiseSVN regex to look for multiple values

Tags: regex, svn

I would like to be able to search the TortoiseSVN log for a list of Revisions or Bug-Ids.

The list could be for any number of individual values or ranges e.g.
search for SVN revisions 1 to 4, or 7, or 12, or 18 to 25 ......

I do not want to look for a range of 1 to 25 which would include revisions that I am not interested in.

I am hoping to define an 'bugtraq:logregex' parameter search string value to accomplish this.

Any advice on this please, would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Nick

Comment: Did you solve this? If so, an answer to your own question would be useful here, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svn log` with multiple `r` parameters like this:

```
svn log -r 1:4 -r 7 -r 12 -r 18:25
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the TortoiseSVN part in your question. This would be the solution in case you wanted to use the command line tool.